# SPRING 3 + JSF 2 + WEBLOGIC 10 ERROR

Tags: spring, weblogic-10.x

i need your help with this error in my proyect spring 3 and weblogic sever,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ELResolver.invoke(Ljavax/el/ELContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:111)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
```

i tried adding el-api-2.2 and el-impl-2.2 and nothing happens and modify my weblogic-application.xml

```
    <wls:application-param>
    <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
    <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
</wls:application-param>

<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>javax.el.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>com.sun.el.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

And adding this segment in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

pleace any help i will be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because weblogic library contain jsf and el, for resolved this error, is necessary adding this segment in weblogic.xml and any description should  be set in false

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>javax.el.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.el.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
        <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring + JSF Integration, you need change JSF EL To Spring: add following code to `faces-config.xml`

```
<application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
</application>
```

Comment: any another idea? help please

Comment: @ggarridov why do you need `<param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>` I don't know about weblogic configuration. I guess your configuration overrided the spring configuration

Comment: i can resolved this problem, my error was in weblogic.xml now all is ok, thanks for all